# Is it possible to stop vim redrawing for every action in a key binding?

Tags: vim

This is purely a visual thing (vim is working properly), but with some key-mappings I have vim set to do multiple operations, eg.

eg, move the selected block up/down with alt j/k.

```
vmap <M-j> Vxp`[v`]
vmap <M-k> VxkP`[v`]
```

This works well but redraws for each operation which is a bit distracting.

So my question is:

Is it possible to set a key-binding to not redraw until the operation is complete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you are looking for

```
:help 'lazyredraw'
```